# How to skip a block of code and go to the desired code in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

so I have asked this problem before but the solution was not as viable as I'd hope.
I needed to run selenium not being headless for it to work but i want to run it headless

Below is the block of codes , where i'd like to access the link in the red box. Problem if i tried to go to class col-box. it will go into the class "hide"
i'd like to skip that class and go into the class lower down where the link is found.

How can I do this?
I'd did this

```
new = driver.find_element_by_class_name('inbox-dataList')
link = new.driver.find_element_by_class_name('col-box')
link1 = link.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
link1
```

Result : `'javascript:void(0);'`

[image: Picure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find using CSS selectors often overlap. So best is you find using XPath. First right click the element, hover on Copy and click XPath. Then try: `link1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('THE XPATH').get_attribute('href')`